# Scala 2.13 Top Level definition alternative & Best Practices

Tags: scala

1. Is there a place somewhere where i can find an exhaustive list of things that are not allowed as top-level object in scala 2.13 ? e.g. implicit Classes. ..
2. What are the current best practices to expose theses kind of object ? Package object ? Companion Object ?
3. Slightly unrelated but, would it be a good practice to declare ADT in Package object ? or better keep them let say in the compilation unit with the module/Service (trait or object) that make use of them ?

Comment: 1. AFAIK, anything that is not a `(abstract) class` / `(sealed) trait` / `object` - 2. Usually, an object that the user can import, and some libraries also provide a trait that users can extend _(on those libraries the object for import extends that trait)_ - 3. Do not use package objects for anything public, just for simple auxiliary functions for internal use.

Comment: Got it !! thanks. Can you elaborate on Point 3 ? One such libray that follow what you say on point 2, would be circe, everything syntax is in package object ? So implicit class for type class ? That doe not count as public stuff ? unless i did not get your point well ...

Comment: Yes that does count as public stuff, you can look at how we expose syntax in [**neotypes**](https://github.com/neotypes/neotypes/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/neotypes/implicits/syntax). Note that `package objects` can also be used to expose simple objects that work as namespaces _(for example syntax objects)_. In general, is recommended not to use them for storing classes or functions that are to be exposed since package objects are treated different by the compiler.

Comment:  for the tips

Comment: BTW, since I have already answered a couple of your question I think it is better to make a disclaimer that I have a very opinionated mindset about many features of Scala, so it is good that you always pick my answers with a grain of slat.

Comment: Opinion are good, it means someone put some thoughts into it. So appreciate the share here !!!!